# Remove id from session hash Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, hash

I'm trying to remove an id from a session hash. I was able to push the id to the `session[]` but now when I try to remove it from the hash, it deletes the id all together in it's entirety from the camp.rb model. I created this rails app with scaffold. Any advice?

```
MODEL - cart.rb

class Cart

    def initialize(array_of_camp_ids = [])
        @camp_ids = array_of_camp_ids
    end

    def camps
        Camp.where(id: @camp_ids)
    end

_____________________________________________________________________


 applicaition_controller.rb

 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_cart

  private

  def set_cart
    session[:cart] ||= []
    @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
  end
end

_____________________________________________________________________

cart_controller.rb

def add_to_compare
  session[:cart] << @camp.id
  redirect_to '/compare'
end                     

_____________________________________________________________________

VIEW - camps.html.rb
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @camp.name %>
</p>

<p>
<%= form_tag(action: "add_to_compare") do %>
  <%= hidden_field :camp_id, value: @camp.id %>
<%= submit_tag "Add to comparison cart" %>
<% end %>
</p>

_____________________________________________________________________

VIEW - cart.html.erb

<tbody>
  <% @cart.camps.each do |camp| %>
    <tr>      
        <td><%= camp.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'remove', camp, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>     
    <tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link_to is calling the destroy action on your cart controller.  This will by default, delete it from the db. If you don't want to do that, you could just do `session.data[:cart].delete @cart.id`.

Comment: Hi Chad,

Thank you for the response. I'm relatively new to RoR. Where would I place this? As a new action on my cart controller or on the cart view? I tried both but I guess I'm saving it wrong.

Comment: If you just want to delete it from the session and not the database you could change the cart controller's destroy action to do what I said instead.